# Angular Module Config block is never getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

Angular Config module is not getting invoked.

In the below code snippet, `app.state.js` is getting invoked, but the config part it's not. Please help me out on this.

This is used in a jhipster application

```
**app.module.js :**

(function() {
'use strict';

 var app= angular
    .module('IloadsApp', [
        'ngStorage',
        'tmh.dynamicLocale',
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'ngResource',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngAria',
        'ngCacheBuster',
        'ngFileUpload',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
        'ui.router',
        'infinite-scroll',
        // jhipster-needle-angularjs-add-module JHipster will add new module here
        'angular-loading-bar'
    ]);
   app.run(run);

run.$inject = ['stateHandler', 'translationHandler'];

function run(stateHandler, translationHandler) {
    stateHandler.initialize();
    translationHandler.initialize();
}
})();


**app.state.js :**

(function() {

'use strict'; 
angular
.module('IloadsApp')
.config(stateConfig);

stateConfig.$inject = ['$statePsrovider'];

alert ("before Inside ");

function stateConfig($stateProvider) {
    alert ("Inside ");
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        abstract: true,

        views: {
            'navbar@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/navbar/navbar.html',
                controller: 'NavbarController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            authorize: ['Auth',
                function (Auth) {
                    return Auth.authorize();
                }
            ],
            translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
            }]
        }
    });
}
alert("After");
})();
```

Comment: you have an injection issue here: `stateConfig.$inject = ['$statePsrovider'];` try again after correcting the label.

Comment: I have corrected the label as stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider']; and tried again. Still the same issue persist

Comment: [Here is](http://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/qrGNVx) a minimal working version. The only things I can think of is that you didn't include app.state.js properly or there is a dependency issue. Try to remove the dependencies to see if this is the case.